# Comparing year and month in Rails ORM

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, date, orm

I'm just starting to learn to use Rails, and have considerable experience in Django. I'm trying to convert a fairly common query into the Rails ORM but can't seem to find a good reference to a database independent solution.

What I want to do is compare the date or month of the created_at field to text submitted from the url. In Django this is simple:

```py
if kwargs.get('year', False):
    # Filter by year
    post_list = Post.objects.filter(posting_date__year = kwargs['year'])
    # Futher filter by month if applicable
    if kwargs.get('month', False):
        post_list = post_list.filter(posting_date__month=kwargs['month'])
```

I can't seem to find a simple *database independent* solution to do the same in Rails. Note that I stress the *database independent* part; I can certainly write my own SQL for this but I beleive strongly in abstraction of code and database.

Comment: rails activerecord/activerelation (ORM) is a 'leaky' abstraction around sql, you should be able to stay 'database independent' but you will often use sql snippets, i.e. `Post.where("title LIKE ?", "#{params[:title_search]}%").order(:title)` - as for filtering on datetime columns, you might want to read this blog post I did on timezones - http://jessehouse.com/blog/2013/11/15/working-with-timezones-and-ruby-on-rails/ - depending on how accurate you want your results to be

Answer (score 0):

This could work

```
def self.by_year(year)
  dt = DateTime.new(year)
  boy = dt.beginning_of_year
  eoy = dt.end_of_year
  where("published_at >= ? and published_at <= ?", boy, eoy)
end
```

but I am not sure it is the best way.